# Как реализовать обновление чата с интервалом в 3 секунды?

Tags: javascript, ajax

При загрузке страницы с помощью ajax запроса генерируется вся переписка. Как можно без потерь производительности реализовать обновление сообщений с интервалом в 3 секунды?

Comment: на словах невозможно

Comment: Нуу,тогда не на словах) Мне бы просто понять по какому принципу

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets

Comment: Очень просто: при ajax-запросе отдавать не всю переписку, а только свежие обновления.

Comment: Ну таймер на 3 сек, в таймер ajax.

Answer (score 1):

без потерь производительности используйте websocket

```html
setInterval(function() {
ваш ajax
}, 3000);
```